"Graphviz" not working with jupyter-notebook on Mac M
I'm currently working on a Jupyter project where I need to display some graphs, but unfortunately, they aren't showing up. I've already successfully installed Graphviz using brew install graphviz. Prior to that, I attempted installation with pip3 install graphviz as well. Despite these installations, Graphviz isn't functioning as expected in my project. I consistently encounter the following error message without any graph output:
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
As a new macOS user, I'm still getting acquainted with the system files. Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Could there be an issue during the installation process, or is it possibly a matter of the 'PATH' configuration?

"I've already successfully installed Graphviz using brew install graphviz." Yes, but that may not be the location that Jupyter is looking to use it. Try what is shown here. Then if that doesn't help, try that last command, the pip install one inside inside the running notebook with the magic version %pip install pygraphviz .... But you want to ise what it says at the bottom of there I suspect, substituting $GRAPHVIZ_DIR for the path.

Also note: apple requires that all components of a program are written in the same architecture. Sometime we got ARM software installed and sometime still Intel one (not all numerical libraries are converted, and if you installed in the past, it keep architecture). So it is a complex problem. Conda may help (but ugly on using with different architectures): you can install components on both architectures (but one arch per virtual environment). In brew: check arch and install dependencies on that arch

@Wayne Thank you very much for your help. Installing Graphviz with brew did work, actually. However, now I can't use pip3 anymore, and I always have to look for alternatives with brew, which is quite annoying.

@GiacomoCatenazzi What I figured out is that you seem to be right: pip3 is not fully supported yet on Apple Silicon. If I'm wrong, please inform me. Thanks

Any chance pip works? pip3 was only a bandaid for while Python 2 and 3 were around. Usually just pip is how things work since that is no longer the case. Brew should install pip if you used it to install Python.

@Wayne: please. We have pip3 and we should use that, and for sure not from brew (brew is a cause of problem: every cask has own interpretation on architecture)

@MahdiAli: AFAIK pip3 works fully on Apple hardware, but he works only on "own" architecture, so if you have python for Intel, it will take just intel stuffs. If you have python for arm, it will install arm stuffs. I just recommend to use conda (anaconda/miniconda): probably it is the best tool for such job (support multi-architecture and multiple interpreters, and it was created for such problems graphiz, numpy, pandas). -- we are still waiting the great unification of conda with pip (but there are some design problem)
